# How to get http parameters using java?

Tags: java, solr

I'm having a solr query "http://localhost:8080/solr/select/?q=A".I need to read the parameter "q" in my java code.How can I get this?

Thanks,
Marshal

Comment: What kind of Java code is at `/select` part of the URL? Servlet? JSP? Filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the query in URL form, you can use URL.getQuery(), and then would have to split the string at `=` and `&` to find the right element, like this:

```
public String getQueryPart(URL url, String key) {
    String query = url.getQuery();
    if(query == null)
       return null;
    String[] parts = query.split("[&=]");
    for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; i+=2) {
       if(parts[i].equals(key)) {
          return parts[i+1];
       }
    }
}
```

If you want to query multiple parameters, better store the split String once in a map and query this multiple times.

And of course, if you are using this in a servlet or similar server-side code called by this exactly URL, there are better ways to get the parameters in the servlet API (like Deepak wrote).

Comment: I think this is not the best way to do this since already the servlet api has a clean way from doing this. I suggest use the answer of @Deepak

Comment: The question did not really say he wants to do this in the code called by this URL - of course, if it is so, better use Deepaks answer.

Answer (score 7):

`request.getParameter("q");` would do the trick.

Comment: I think i should be more specific.I'm trying to customizing QueryElevationComponent.java of solr. In that java file i need to get the q parameter.When i'm trying to use 'request.getParameter("q")',it showing error.Is there any packages that i should import or should i have to extend class?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on you context.
From where are you trying to get this param? How are you using Solr exactly?

BTW, `/select` is simply a part of a URL used to map requests to the main Solr servlet called (wait for it...) [SolrServlet](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/servlet/SolrServlet.html) - `org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrServlet` (deprecated from v4, now `solr.StandardRequestHandler` is used), which is, due to the fact that it handles search requests, also sometimes referred to as Solr Server.